# How to invoke Erlang function with variable?

Tags: erlang

```
4> abs(1).
1
5> X = abs.
abs
6> X(1).
** exception error: bad function abs
7> erlang:X(1).
1
8>
```

Is there any particular reason why I have to use the module name when I invoke a function with a variable? This isn't going to work for me because, well, for one thing it is just way too much syntactic garbage and makes my eyes bleed. For another thing, I plan on invoking functions out of a list, something like (off the top of my head):

```
[X(1) || X <- [abs, f1, f2, f3...]].
```

Attempting to tack on various module names here is going to make the verbosity go through the roof, when the whole point of what I am doing is to reduce verbosity.

EDIT: Look here: http://www.erlangpatterns.org/chain.html The guy has made some pipe-forward function. He is invoking functions the same way I want to above, but his code doesn't work when I try to use it. But from what I know, the guy is an experienced Erlang programmer - I saw him give some keynote or whatever at a conference (well I saw it online).

Did this kind of thing used to work but not anymore? Surely there is a way I can do what I want - invoke these functions without all the verbosity and boilerplate.

EDIT: If I am reading the documentation right, it seems to imply that my example at the top should work (section 8.6) http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html

Comment: `X = abs, X(1).` doesn't work because Erlang doesn't consider an atom bound to a variable a function. `X = erlang, Y = abs, X:Y(1).` should work, though. The colon separating both parts tells Erlang it's a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know abs is an atom, not a function. [...] Why does it work when the module name is used?

[The documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78111) explains that (slightly reorganized):

> ```
> ExprM:ExprF(Expr1,...,ExprN)
> ```
>
> each of `ExprM` and `ExprF` must be an atom or an expression that
>   evaluates to an atom. The function is said to be called by using the
>   fully qualified function name.
>
> ```
> ExprF(Expr1,...,ExprN)
> ```
>
> `ExprF`
>   must be an atom or evaluate to a fun.
>   If ExprF is an atom the function is said to be called by using the implicitly qualified function name.

- When using fully qualified function names, Erlang expects *atoms* or *expression that evaluates to **atoms***. In other words, you have to bind `X` to an *atom*: `X = atom.` That's exactly what you provide.
- But in the second form, Erlang expects either an *atom* or an *expression that evaluates to a **function***. Notice that last word. In other words, if you do *not* use fully qualified function name, you have to bind `X` to a function: `X = fun module:function/arity.`

Comment: "Quite clear?"  The documentation isn't THAT clear, in fact I posted the same docs above in an edit before you did.  I think it is confusing.  Having said that, I accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 8):

In the expression `X=abs`, **abs** is not a function but an atom. If you want thus to define a function,you can do so:

```
D = fun erlang:abs/1.
```

or so:

```
X = fun(X)->abs(X) end.
```

Comment: To add details: the reason why the syntax `fun M:F/Arity` with `Arity` being specified is because Erlang allows many functions to have the same name. The *unique* part of a function is the function name *and* the *arity* (how many arguments it takes). Therefore just the function name is not specific enough to know which function is used; the name and the number of arguments is required.

Comment: I know abs is an atom.not a function.  But you invoke the function using an atom as a name.  Look to my example above.  Why does it work when the module name is used?

Comment: @user3355020 , after the operation of pattern matching X is equal abs in a literal sense. I.e. wherever can be used atom abs can be used and X. Cool,right? One of the reasons I like Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
X = fun(Number) -> abs(Number) end.
```

**Updated:**

After looking at the discussion more, it seems like you're wanting to apply multiple functions to some input.

There are two projects that I haven't used personally, but I've starred on Github that may be what you're looking for.

Both of these projects use parse transforms:

- fun_chain https://github.com/sasa1977/fun_chain
- pipeline https://github.com/stolen/pipeline

Pipeline is unique because it uses a special syntax:

```
Result = [fun1, mod2:fun2, fun3] (Arg1, Arg2).
```

Of course, it could also be possible to write your own function to do this using a list of `{module, function}` tuples and applying the function to the previous output until you get the result.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Yup I knew I could do that, but I don't want to do that.  I want a list of atoms I can use to invoke functions with.

Comment: @user3355020 are the functions in different modules or are they all in the same module?

Comment: They could potentially be in different modules.

Comment: @user3355020 I updated my answer with some projects you may be interested in using for applying input to a list of functions.